# Parametrize location where eclipse settings are saved

Tags: eclipse

We are a team of developers that because of "business" requirements have to develop in sessions opened in a Windows 2008 server machine. Meaning that we have to share an eclipse installation.

As we all keep individual workspaces, it is not a big deal (I think) but it is annoying and potentially dangerous that we overwrite Eclipse settings for each other so we have to restore to our workspace every time we restart eclipse.

Question is, is it possible to configure the location where the settings are saved?  Ideally managed by the user logged in, but even with some parameter in the shortcut would be ok.

Also, any other idea about how to deal with it would be very appreciated.

Many thanks,

Comment: What version of Eclipse?

Comment: Version is Eclipse 3.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never knew that Eclipse was re-entrant.

Eclipse starts with a little Workspace Launcher window that allows you to prompt for the workspace on startup.  If the little Workspace Launcher window has been disabled, you can turn it back on at Window -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown -> Workspaces (in Eclipse 3.7).  In Eclipse 3.4, there's no Workspaces preference page.

Check the box next to "Prompt for workspace on startup" to have Eclipse start with the little Workspace Launcher window.

Every developer has to do this for the little Workspace Launcher window to appear.

As far as I know, your workspace also keeps track of your Eclipse settings.

Comment: Thanks, I knew this, problem is every developer that starts eclipse overwrites "default" workspace, and so it will be a matter of time until someone starts in someone else workspace. This is the behaviour I would like to change.

Comment: @pedromarce: I added a line to my answer.  No developer can have a default workspace.

Answer (score 2):

When you install eclipse, you can put it into [multi-user](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html) mode.  Then making the install read-only will make sure different users don't overwrite each other.  It will also set a default workspace (`osgi.instance.area`) based on `@user.home`, so doing nothing will bring up a different workspace per user.  However it's generally a better practice to deliberately manage your workspaces, using `-data` or the workspace launcher mentioned by @Gilbert.